# Express js with forever does not listen to external ip

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have uploaded my express js app to my VPS which has static IP.

My code that will listen to port and host is this:

```
app.listen(8888, "0.0.0.0");
```

Then I start it with forever:

```
forever start main.js
```

My page is accessible when I open it via localhost, when I try to open via external ip address it doesn't.

Did I miss something?

My iptables in Ubuntu Server 14.04 is this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8888

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The main interesting this is that I can access to this VPS remotely via SSH.

Comment: Might be firewall is blocking port.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Have you checked that the firewall is not blocking the connection?

Comment: @AdnanUmer added iptables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a firewall such as iptables? You may need to open your port 8888 if this is the case.

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT`

Note that this rule will be lost when if your server is restarted. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/66890/how-can-i-make-a-specific-set-of-iptables-rules-permanent

Comment: This is still unaccessible via my browser